# Angularjs - How to set value of Global variable according to one of the response data element

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, global-variables, local-variables

I want to set the value of glovalvar according to defined in function hello
I am getting response data & according to that I want to set globalvar Value.
Here is snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  var globalvar;
  $scope.globalvar='';
  $scope.hello = function()
  {
    //here I want to set the value of glovalvar.I am getting response              data & according to that I want to set globalvar Value.
      //For an example I am creating this funtion.
    //How can I achieve this.
    //I tries below code:
    $scope.globalvar="ee";
  }
  console.log($scope.globalvar)
});
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

    </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    {{globalvar}}
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call the function `$scope.hello()` before `console.log($scope.globalvar)`

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  var globalvar;
  $scope.globalvar='';
  $scope.hello = function()
  {
    //here I want to set the value of glovalvar.
    //How can I achieve this.
    //I tries below code:
    $scope.globalvar="ee";
  }
  $scope.hello()
  console.log($scope.globalvar)
});
```

Comment: Its working. But is there any other way. In my application, I required that I want to set the global variable to certain value and through if condition I will check that value, If its true then it will disable the field.If I used function method like u mention above then I need to call it on page, but if its possible without function then it will b great @albert